# Which F1 season had the fewest number of wins by someone outside the top two drivers?

Tags: formula-1

In 2021, 18 of the 22 races were won by Lewis or Max, with the remaining 4 races won by other drivers. Was there a season where there were less than 4 races won by drivers outside the top two in the championship?. For instance, if a season had 17 races and two drivers won 8 times each, that's a total of 16 wins, and only 1 race would have been won by a driver outside the top two.

Answer (score 1):

There have been 5 seasons in which two drivers won every race except one:

- **1950**. There were 7 races, with Juan Manuel Fangio and Nino Farina winning 3 each; the remaining race was the Indy 500, won by Johnnie Parsons.
- **1952**. There were 8 races, with Alberto Ascari winning 6; Piero Taruffi and Troy Ruttman won the other two.
- **1963**. There were 10 races, with Jim Clark winning 7 and Graham Hill winning 2; the remaining race was won by John Surtees.
- **1988**. There were 16 races, with Ayrton Senna winning 8 and Alain Prost winning 7; the remaining race was won by Gerhard Berger.
- **2023**. There were 22 races, with Max Verstappen winning 19 and Sergio Peréz winning 2; the remaining race was won by Carlos Sainz Jr.

There have been plenty of other occasions in which drivers outside the top two have picked up three or fewer wins between them, but the above examples are the most notable.